# Rounding large float to int

Tags: c++

**Problem**: I'm looking for a way of rounding some `float` `f` to the closest `int` in general -- especially if the `f` is large. Mathematically speaking I'd like to compute the following function

[image: formula2]

where script `T` denotes the set of `int`s representable by my machine. In case of ties (eg. `.5`) `r(f)` can be defined arbitrarily.

---

**Current Code**: Below my current solution including two unsatisfying `float` examples (in `main`):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

template <class T>
T projection(T const min, T t, T const max) {
   return std::max(std::min(t, max), min);
}

template <class Out, class In>
Out repr(In in) {
   using Limits = std::numeric_limits<Out>;
   auto next = [](Out val) {
      auto const zero = static_cast<In>(0);
      return std::nexttoward(static_cast<In>(val), zero);
   };
   return projection(next(Limits::lowest()), std::round(in), next(Limits::max()));
};

int main() {
   std::cout
      << repr<int>(std::numeric_limits<float>::max()) << " "
      << repr<int>(static_cast<float>(std::numeric_limits<int>::max())) << "\n";
}
```

On my machine with `32`bit `int`s this prints:

```
2147483520 2147483520
```

Short elaboration: For the upper bound, `next` computes the next smaller `float` that can be safely `static_cast`ed to `int` (analogously for lower bound). This is necessary as my `float` examples in `main` demonstrate: Without `next`, `repr` involves undefined behavior of casting (at least) `std::numeric_limits<int>::max() + 1` as `float` to `int` in which this number is not representable.

The obvious downside of my `repr` is that it is incorrect in the mathematical sense: For large `float`s (eg. `std::numeric_limits<float>::max()`) it doesn't return `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`.

---

**Questions:**

1. Is this there an easier way to solve the problem (easier in the sense of less manual number crunching and more delegating to `std`-functions)?
2. How can `repr` be made correct (in the mathematical sense) with fully defined behavior only (no undefined and no implementation defined behavior)?
3. So far I've been talking about `int` and `float` but (as templates already suggested) this should only be a start. What about combinations

   - `double` and `long` or
   - `double` and `long long`?

Comment: What about using [`std::round`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round)? Are there any subtle issues with it or you were not aware of its existence?

Comment: `std::round` returns `float`, I need return value `int`.

Comment: No, if you use (5) to (12) forms (`lround`, `llround`), they return an integer.

Comment: Not for eg `std::numeric_limits<float>::max()` or am I missing something?

Comment: Ohh I see, you can check for failures though (if the type is not large enough), see the documentation (under #Error handling). But of course if the number is larger than the desired integer max value, you have no way of doing it "correctly".

Comment: If I use `lround` or `llround` I have a `long` or `long long` that I'd have to project instead. Ok sure -- this answers 2. But error handling is even more involved than my current code.

Comment: Helper comments: Ignoring signed numbers for a second, there are 5 possible regimes: 1) Floats smaller than `.5`, 2) floats larger than `.5` with a fractional part, 3) as 2, but > `INT_MAX`), 3) floats without a fractional part `<= INT_MAX` (exactly representable) and 5) floats without a fractional part `>INT_MAX`. Not all regimes may exist on an implementation; 3 in particular is theoretical.

Comment: If your concern is robustness, put it into a double, add 0.5, then take the floor. Then check against INT_MAX/MIN or equivalent for the integer type you are using.